# Recording Event Logs in a DB from a Smart-Contract

Tags: events, rinkeby, logs

I have created a smart-contract and deployed to the Rinkeby Network, it has a client-side application which has been established with React. Now, I would like to observe and audit every transaction or callback happens in my smart-contract and I need to record these events whenever it happens. In other words, I need to track the transaction near-real-time and record the logs to my SQL or InfluxDB directly.

Would you please show me a way how to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for solidity events using `myContract.events.MyEvent([options][, callback])` with web3 (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events).

Note that you have to connect to your node via websocket in order to subscribe to events.